# Using an ULN2803 with Netduino

Tags: microcontroller, netduino

I want to be able to switch on a device that requires 5v and 100mA from a Netduino. From looking on the web, I believe I need to use a Darlington array in order to meet the current requirements (since the Netduino pins are only at 8mA max).  Is a ULN2803 the right component to use?  Can it generate what I need with the 3.3v of the Netduino?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ULN2803 is generally meant to work with 5 V it seems, but based on some of the datasheets it might be able to supply 100 mA with 3.3 V in.  The related ULN2805 appears to function better at lower voltages.

If you're looking for a *single* low-side driver (where the device is always connected to the positive supply while you switch the ground), you can use a logic-level N-channel MOSFET ([tutorial](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html)).

If you're looking to switch several loads, a [high current shift register](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=734) might be of use to you, and it also can save some I/O pins at the expense of some more complicated driving logic

Comment: Excellent. I'll check out the N-channel MOSFET, which looks to be exactly what I need. The tutorial was good. I found another great tutorial at http://digital-diy.com/Handy-Tips/digi-tip-logic-level-fets-n-channel.html that helped as well.

Comment: Follow up: the logic-level N-channel MOSFET works like a champ! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The 100mA current requirement is easily met. On page 2 of the [datasheet](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets/90/366828_DS.pdf), you can see that 3V will provide for up to 300mA sink current.