# Can I replace this circuit with an IC?

Tags: arduino, led, driver

I moved my Arduino-logic-level-5V-to-12V-LED strip circuit off project board and onto Veroboard and I'm very proud to say everything worked first time:

[image]

(I'm not at all proud of the soldering job, so you don't get to see that.)

So this is the point where you all tell me I can replace the whole shebang with a $0.65 IC. The LED strips pull a few hundred mA per channel and I want to drive them off the Arduino's PWM pins. I've found the [ULN2803A](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet2/5/0w2oz7jig6lt2chlgy7joisuwipy.pdf), but that's 8 Darlington Pair array in a DIP18 package, I want a 3 or 4 Darlington Pair array in a DIP8 or thereabouts. [This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6145/using-an-uln2803-with-netduino) might actually contain the answer I'm looking for, but I don't know enough to even work that out.

Secondary question: how do you even know things like the ULN2803A exist? I happened upon it randomly and from there I worked out that "transistor array" was the search term I wanted. But aside from simply hanging around here, how does one answer the question, "What IC can I buy that will replace this portion of this circuit?"

Comment: @RMAAlmeida Sorry, what's E&R? I'm just curious because it seems like a good thing, and I'd like to make sure I use this platform as efficiently as possible. Thank you, sorry about being off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I found was an ULN2065B, in a DIP-14. I used Farnell's parametric search to do this, but you could also use Digi-key, or a vendor independent site like FindChips or Octopart.

I think you're going to struggle to get DIP-8 for four channels: there would not be a pin available for ground, unless it used some kind of serial interface to communicate. You might be able to find a triple driver in this: one pin for ground, three for control signals, three outputs and maybe a pin for Vcc, if the chip requires it.

Comment: http://export.farnell.com/bipolar-transistors-bjt-arrays

Answer (score 6):

> "Secondary question: how do you even know things like the ULN2803A exist?"

Search Google for something like "transistor array".  Add words like "IC" or "semiconductor" to weed out unrelated stuff.

http://www.google.com/search?q=transistor+array+semiconductor

finds

http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=ULQ2003ADR2G

When you find a manufacturer's listing of a specific part that looks vaguely relevant, use the manufacturer's site navigation to "go up one directory" and see what similar parts they have.  That page has a breadcrumbs navigation at the top "Home >  Products >  Product Catalog >  Drivers >  Load / Relay Drivers >  ULN2003"

Click "Load / Relay Drivers" to see similar stuff.

Comment: At first I thought I was going to see another google answer for someone. +1 for teaching a process that I know, but do not think about, and is probably the most effective way to find a component.

Comment: The problem is, I didn't know that "transistor array" was what I needed to search for, I think I found the above part by searching "lots of transistors on a chip". And as I said, as mentioned in the other thread I linked, a "buffer" chip might be what I actually want. I don't even know the right questions to ask!

Comment: Yeah, neither do I.  :)  Just comes from experience.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options for "ULN2803A"
http://ciiva.com/CloudSearch/SearchComponent?searchCondition=ULN2803A

And for each "ULN2803A", you can find their alternatives on [Ciiva](http://ciiva.com)
E.g,
http://ciiva.com/CloudSearch/Component/997843/stmicroelectronics-uln2803a
[image]